# TypeError when saving a Django model that contains an ImageField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a basic model for which I've added an `ImageField`.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, editable=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """
            Field to show in the related models admin site.
        """
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        # order of drop-down list items
        ordering = ('name',)

        # plural form in admin view
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Save slug when saving model.
            Slug saved only if not existant, to avoid duplicity of urls.
        """
        if not self.id:
            # new object to create
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)[:50]

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I try to create/update an item from the `admin` section by setting an image in the `ImageField`, I get the following error (this error doesn't appear when the `ImageField` isn't set):

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/app/category/8/change/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 544, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 211, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1512, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 53, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1449, in changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1007, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "/home/hakim/project/app/models.py", line 103, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 796, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 824, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 886, in _save_table
    for f in non_pks]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 886, in <listcomp>
    for f in non_pks]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 292, in pre_save
    file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 91, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 53, in save
    name = self.get_available_name(name, max_length=max_length)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 77, in get_available_name
    while self.exists(name) or (max_length and len(name) > max_length):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 394, in exists
    return os.path.exists(self.path(name))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 407, in path
    return safe_join(self.location, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 283, in location
    return abspathu(self.base_location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 369, in abspath
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
```

And the relevant part of `settings.py`:

```
# Location of uploaded images

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),


# URL of uploaded images

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: How about change with `super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`, does it work?

Comment: @SancaKembang No I still get the same error.

Comment: are you has two or more objects with same name?

Comment: @SancaKembang I have another model named `Category`, but it's in a separate app.

Comment: Your error is focused on `line 103, in save; super().save(*args, **kwargs)` what happend when you remove this `save` function?

Comment: @SancaKembang The error persists even if I remove the overriden save method, as long as I'm sending an image in the `ImageField`.

Comment: please show me your `views.py`

Comment: @SancaKembang This error appears in the admin section.

Comment: If you know how to debug, I'd put a breakpoint in that `path = os.fspath(path)` line and run it through the debugger. Apparently it's getting a tuple, but I have no idea where it's coming from. Is your `MEDIA_ROOT` a tuple? Even if it were, I think it shouldn't survive the appending of your `upload_to` and make it to that line that is causing the error.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida You were right that was the error (I had a typo in my `settings.py`: I forgot a comma at the end of the `MEDIA_ROOT` variable). Could you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @h4k1m Wait, I'm confused. `MEDIA_ROOT` wasn't a tuple, now you made it a tuple and it's working? `MEDIA_ROOT` is supposed to be a string. Or did you now remove a comma that was there?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida it's the other way around. I had before a typo (a trailing comma at the end that I had to remove), i.e. `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media),`.

Comment: upload_to='images/' forgot the slash.  also take care of this on your settings.py STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates the problem is a tuple being present instead of a string in the following line, where `path` is the location to upload the file:

```
path = os.fspath(path)
```

Since `upload_to` is correctly set to a string in the model, I figured the problem might be related to `MEDIA_ROOT`, which turned out to be a tuple (as clarified in comments). Making it a string solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By this error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
```

I think the error is in the image field of the form. In save() do the first:

```
print(self.image)
```

To see what you are saving, it will be a tuple instead of an string.

Comment: I've added a print inside my model's `save()`, and the type of `self.image` was `<class 'django.db.models.fields.files.ImageFieldFile'>`. When I print it I get the name of the image file. Did you mean the field in the form?

Comment: Try to print the path , self.image.url

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had it like this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT=[os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')]
```

Writing it this way solved the error:

```
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```